# How to check for empty value coming (Jquery)?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code:

```
$('#search_field').keyup(function () {
    LIBRARY.ajaxGet('{$addUrl}', {name: $(this).val()}, function(data) {
        $('.contacts').html(data['html']);
    });
});
```

I need `$(this).val()` to be the value for the `name` property if it is not empty. If it *is*, then the object should be empty.

Comment: P.S. if `#search_field` is an input element, you can use `this.value` inside the event handler to get the input value. You may use `if( this.value != '' )` to check whether there is some value in there…

Comment: You should probably implement minimum length for the search query, so that the request is not send for search terms with just one or two characters. (e.g. `if( this.value.length > 3 )`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to create the object outside, perform the check, and *then* pass it in:

```
$('#search_field').keyup(function () {
    var nameObj = {};
    if ($(this).val()) {
        nameObj.name = $(this).val();
    }

    LIBRARY.ajaxGet('{$addUrl}', nameObj, function (data) {
        $('.contacts').html(data['html']);
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I understand exactly what you need, but I think you want to see if the value in your input box after a `keyup` is not empty, then you can do something like:

```
$('#search_field').keyup(function () {
   if(this.value.length > 0) { 
      // rest of your code ...
   }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Try putting your attributes object in an variable:

```
var myParams = {};

if($(this).val().length > 0){
  myParams = { "name": $(this).val() };
}

LIBRARY.ajaxGet('{$addUrl}', myParams, function(data){
  $('.contacts').html(data['html']);
});
```